# replace power in nexus 7004 chassis

Tags: cisco-nexus

I have the following chassis :

```
1x N7K-C7004 with full powers and fan
1x N7K-F248XP-25E
2x N7K-SUP2
```

i want to know is there any difference in energy consumption if i use N7K-AC-6.0KW instead of N7K-AC-3.0KW ?

Comment: Everything else being equal, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends.

In theory, the PSU takes from mains what its load consumes plus a bit for its own loss. In practice, PSU efficiency often depends on the load percentage that it's running on - roughly, the lower the load ratio, the lower the efficiency.

All N7k PSUs are 80plus silver certificated (Cisco claims "more than 90% efficient"), so a substantial change isn't to be expected. It really depends on what load level you're running them on. In extreme, the 6kW PSU could be slightly more efficient than the 3kW (when the latter's load is close to 100%) but chances are it'll pull a bit more.

Comment: Exactly. A 3k @ 80% load may be more efficient than a 6k @ 40%. I can't guess what that difference might be.

Comment: Do you have any idea how much power it will consume with %20 load and 3k power?

Comment: @Blackmetal No, not really. 80plus silver mandates 85% efficiency at 20% load (@ 230V), 10% (for the 6k) isn't defined. Since Cisco claims 90% overall, I'd roughly guess the 6k pulls no more than ~25W more.

Comment: so with 6k PSU and my configuration that I explained in above it will pull around 40-50w in the worst case? when I execute show env why does it shows its reserving 120w for SUP and 750w for the board and ..., when it reserves the power it will not pull the power from pdu?

Comment: @Blackmetal 20% for the 3k means 600W. The 6k might pull around 625W in the same scenario.